# Call iOS pan and pinch recognizer from another class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing a SpriteKit application in iOS using Swift, and I have implemented pan and pinch gestures for my map. The code looks like this:

```
    //Zoom recognizer
    let pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("pinch:"))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

    // Move recognizer
    let pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("pan:"))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)


func pinch(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){

    var anchorPoint: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
    anchorPoint = convertPointFromView(anchorPoint)

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {

        let anchorPointInMySKNode: CGPoint = world!.convertPoint(anchorPoint, fromNode: self)
        world!.setScale(world!.xScale * sender.scale)

        let mySKNodeAnchorPointInScene: CGPoint = self.convertPoint(anchorPointInMySKNode, fromNode: world!)
        let translationOfAnchorInScene = CGPointSubtract(anchorPoint, point2: mySKNodeAnchorPointInScene)

        world!.position = CGPointAdd(world!.position, point2: translationOfAnchorInScene)

        sender.scale = 1.0
    }
}

func pan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){

        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: sender.view)
    }

    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed){

        var translation: CGPoint = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)
        translation = CGPointMake(-translation.x, translation.y)

        world!.position = CGPointSubtract(world!.position, point2: translation)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: sender.view)
    }
}
```

The code works fine but currently it is written in GameScene.swift class, however it would be better if could create a separate class called Gestures.swift and just call which ever gesture I want. I have tried several approaches but none of them work. The two main issues are how to address the selector in the GestureRecognizer function and how to pass the parent node which is in my case world initialized inside GameScene.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegation. I have used something of this nature in my games (but in obj-c). Delegation is the way to go.

Here are a few resources I would recommend.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHx4nE7EMic

http://swift.exomachina.com/swift-tutorial-8-from-one-scene-to-another-using-delegate-protocol/